# C# mediatr register handlers by filter

Tags: c#, .net, mediatr

I have a DDD project. In Application layer there are lot of Mediator handlers. This layer is used by two web apps. One is main and second is for audit view.
Main application uses multiple services and et. that are injected in handlers. Audit app basically uses only AuditDbContext (~10 handlers).
Problem is that if I want to register services like

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(options =>
{
    options.Lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped;
    options.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
});
```

then it register all handlers, and I get error, that some services can't be constructed. Now as workaround I just created dummy services, that are injected. But I don't like this solution.
Is it possible to register just part of handlers?

I tried to create new interface, like IAuditHandler and then register all handlers, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put the handlers for each type into their own project. This helps with the separation of concerns. That way you can register only the ones you want by doing this:

```
var assembly = typeof(SomeTypeFromTheProjectYouWantToRegister).Assembly;
options.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(assembly);
```